# load data from selected table row in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, odbc

I'm trying to user mouse event to display the selected row from jtable in other text field but when i run it and clicked on any row it's coming with this message java.sql.Exception [microsoft ][odbc microsoft access drive] data type mismatch in criteria exception

please any idea can help

this is the code :

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    try
    {
        int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        String Table_Click = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
        String Sql= "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE ID='" + Table_Click +"' ";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(Sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            String Add1= rs.getString("ID");
            jTextField_ID.setText(Add1);
            String AddBrNa= rs.getString("UserName");
            jTextField_UN.setText(AddBrNa);
            String AddBrAdd= rs.getString("Password");
            jPasswordField_Pass.setText(AddBrAdd);
            String AddBrYear= rs.getString("FName");
            jTextField_FN.setText(AddBrYear);
            String AddBrCourse= rs.getString("LName");
            jTextField_LN.setText(AddBrCourse);
            String AddBrSec= rs.getString("DateCreated");
            jTextField_date.setText(AddBrSec);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "errorif");
        }
        else
        {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to user mouse event to display the selected row from jtable
>   in other text field

There's no need to use `MouseListener` to do that. Just implement a [ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) instead, that will be executed even if the selection change is made through keyboard or code:

```
jTable1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {            
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // Your code here
    }
};
```

If you still want to use `MouseListener` then I'd suggest you make this change:

```
//int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int row = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
```

Because you can't be sure the row selection will change *before* this event is triggered. I'm not sure but I would say a `MouseEvent` should have precedence over a `ListSelectionEvent`.

However be aware this`row` index belongs to the `view`, not the model, so the following line may not return the expected result if your table is a sorted one:

```
String Table_Click = (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
```

It should be:

```
String Table_Click = (jTable1.getValueAt(row,0).toString());
```

Having said this, the proper use of `PreparedStatemen` is the one @camickr just pointed out:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE ID = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql); //
pst.setString(1, Table_Click) // assuming the ID is a varchar, since you enclosed it into ''
```

Also be aware that you're accessing your database in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). You should do that in a separate thread and update Swing components in the EDT. [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) sounds like a good match in this case.

Comment: +1 A number of very valid remarks. Only one I am missing is to get that db-access away from the EDT

Comment: `so the following line may not return the expected result if your table is a sorted one:jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row,0)` look into the implementation before making such statement.

Comment: @Sage I think there's a misunderstanding here. `JTable.getValueAt(row, column)` converts `row` and `column` indexes to the appropriate model indexes before calling `TableModel.getValueAt(row,column)`. But in this case `jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row,0)` clearly doesn't: OP is requesting the cell value directly to the model but `row` is the index in the view, not the model.

Comment: @dic19, yes, that is why we should have mentioned the `JTable.getValueAt(row, column)` function :)

Comment: @Sage alright then I second that :) But let's agree my statement is right but I could make a better suggestion. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @dic19, i didn't say your statement is wrong. But we should have mentioned the better and simpler implementation first

Comment: @Sage agree, I just wanted to point out that is necessary to convert the index from view to model. I've just edited :D

Answer (score 3):

`java.sql.Exception [microsoft ][odbc microsoft access drive] data type mismatch in criteria exception`: is nothing to do with your table. Check your SQL query. Most likely your ID is an integer type but you are checking it as string, inside your `where` clause:

```
WHERE ID='" + Table_Click +"'
```

Comment: Great men thinks alike ;) +1 back to you too

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `PreparedStatement` to make the SQL easier. If you do need to use an int as suggested by Sage then you can do:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE ID = ?";
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setInt(1, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all,

this is working fine:

String Sql= "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE ID=" + Table_Click;

Comment: This is not how this site works. As a OP, you should not post `Thank you, Thanks all` type post. [Check here to see](http://stackoverflow.com/about), how this site should be used.